# PHP shorthand for "if (!isset($var)) $var = 1;"

Tags: php, shorthand

Is there a shorthand version for, "if this variable isn't set yet, then set it"?

Example:

```
switch ($Frequency) {
    case 'Once':
        doSomethingSpecific();
        break;
    case 'Daily':
        $Message = 'Event will occur every day at the same time.';
    case 'Weekly':
        if (!isset($Message)) $Message = 'Event will occur every week on the same day of the week, at the same time.';
    case 'Monthly':
        if (!isset($Message)) $Message = 'Event will occur every month on the same day of the week.';
        doSomething($Message);
        break;
}
```

Comment: `$var = (!isset($var)) ? 1 : $var;`

Comment: IMHO, this could be written better to be more clear about what you are doing. I would suggest to check if `$Frequency == "Once"` then `doSomethingSpecific()` else then set the message and call `doSomething()` at the end.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Thanks, it's just an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's called the ternary operator:

```
$var = isset($var) ? $var : "Some default";
```

Since PHP 5.3 there's a shorthand version for this as well:

```
$var = isset($var) ?: "Some default";
```

And an alternate version for PHP 5.3+:

```
isset($var) ?: $var = "Some default";
```